# fmincon MATLAB: "No Feasible Solution Found!"

Tags: matlab, optimization, feasibility

I have the following code and I need to use "fmincon" to solve a model with linear constraints and a nonlinear objective function:

```
A = [Aeq ; Aineq];
x0 = zeros(size(A,2),1);
x0(1:T:(n+2)*T) = I0;
lb = zeros(size(A,2),1);
ub = Inf*zeros(size(A,2),1);
options = optimset('fmincon');

% fmincon:
[x , fval , exitflag , output , lambda] = fmincon(@MP_ObjF1 , x0 , Aineq , bineq , Aeq , beq , 0 , Inf , [] , options);
```

And this is the function:

```
function ObjF = MP_ObjF1(x)

global n;
global T;
global h;
global Total_Tcij; %A row vector of T arrays

ObjF = 0;
for t=1:T
    x_I_set = ((1:T:(n+2)*T)+(t-1))';
    x_I = x(x_I_set);
    HC = x_I*h; %"x_I" is a row vector, and "h" is a column vector.
    newObjF = (Total_Tcij(t) + HC)*x((n+2)*T+t);
    ObjF = (ObjF + newObjF);
end

end
```

The data required to run the model is as follows (which is the result of the codes being run up to the above part of the codes) :

```
n = 2;
T = 3;
h = [5 ; 5 ; 5 ; 5];
Total_Tcij = [10    10    10];
```

---

```
Aineq =

Columns 1 through 14

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0

Column 15

 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

---

```
Aeq =

Columns 1 through 14

-1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     4     0
 1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     4
 0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0    -1     0     0     0     0     0    13     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0    13
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     4     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1     1     0     0     4
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     4     4
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     7     7
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

Column 15

 0
 0
 4
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 7
 0
 0
 4
 0
 0
 4
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 7
 0
 0
 1
```

---

```
bineq =
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
```

---

```
beq =

-4
 3
 5
 3
 4
 6
 5
 3
 5
 0
-4
-3
 0
 0
 4
 3
 7
13
 0
 2
 7
 1
 1
 1
```

The result is the following warning:

```
Warning: Trust-region-reflective method does not currently solve this type of problem, using active-set (line search) instead. 
> In fmincon at 439

No feasible solution found.

fmincon stopped because the size of the current search direction is less than twice the default value of the step size tolerance but constraints were not satisfied to within the selected value of the constraint tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>
```

However, I'm quite sure the program has a feasible solution; should I set anything e.g. regarding the search direction or the constraint tolerance? I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Please provide data and parameters in a reasonable format (textfile or m-file) and on a download source which does not require login. You may also put your data into your question, format it as code and a scroll bar will be added.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I made the changes you mentioned to my Question above. I appreciate your help to my problem with the model.

Comment: I0 is needed to run the code. Please add it to the question. Also, I know you're not using them (but you set them up anyways): for `ub`, `Inf*zeros(...)` will give you `NaN`. If you want `Inf`, use `Inf*ones(...)`. As a preliminary answer, the first warning tells you that the Trust-Region algorithm can't solve this problem. You should change the algorithm using [optimoptions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html): `options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp',)` for instance (choose the algorithm [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html))

Comment: Yes! This was left out of my sight! It is definitely 'ub = Inf*ones(...)'. Thanks! I'll change it and add 'options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp')' and see the result; I hope it'll be solved. Thank you!